# Index not showing in dataframe - need to display corresponding index then delete columns based on threshold using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isnull, data-cleaning

I just started learning Python so any help is much appreciated.

So the overarching purpose here is for data exploration + data cleaning.

The function I've written below outputs a dataframe that shows the percentage of missing values from every column.

```
def missing_values_table(df):
    missing_vals = df.isnull().sum()
    # Boolean check of all value to True for all null values, then sums for total count.
    percent_conversion = 100 * df.isnull().sum()/len(df)
    # Percent conversion.
    combined_table = pd.concat([missing_vals, percent_conversion], axis=1)
    # Merging dataframes.
    table_renamed = combined_table.rename(columns = 
        {0:'Missing Values', 1:'Percentage'})
    # Giving column labels.
    table_renamed.sort_values(['Percentage'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
    # Sort descending.
    return table_renamed
```

Problematic output (it's missing index that will show me where they are in the original dataframe...which is massive):

```
                          Missing Values  Percentage
Engine_Horsepower                 375906   93.712932
Pushblock                         375906   93.712932
Enclosure_Type                    375906   93.712932
Blade_Width                       375906   93.712932
[...]
```

Desired output:

```
                          Missing Values  Percentage
32 Engine_Horsepower                 375906   93.712932
15 Pushblock                         375906   93.712932
3  Enclosure_Type                    375906   93.712932
17 Blade_Width                       375906   93.712932
[...]
```

The numbers correspond to the column number from the original dataframe, pre-sorted.

Only after investigating these individually to confirm that these columns can be deleted, I'll delete the columns based on a threshold (50%+ null values, delete).

Comment: First off. Don't use `df.isnull().sum()` to get the percentage. Use `df.isnull().mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your integer location of the columns, make the columns MultiIndex

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([range(len(df.columns)), df.columns])
```

And then the filtering and summary of nulls will keep the location

```
threshold = .4
df[df.columns[df.isnull().mean() < threshold]]
```

And this will do the first part of your function

```
df_null_summary = pd.concat([df.isnull().sum(), df.isnull().mean()], axis=1, keys=['Missing Values', 'Percentage'])
```

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful.

Comment: So in the end this will be 2 functions - The first one is the code I wrote up there for general exploration purposes (making sure the columns can be delete, etc.). I'm a little confused as to why the index doesn't print out.

The second is the exactly your code here - which is to delete based on a threshold.

Comment: I probably don't understand your purpose completely, but I see no need for any function. This one line of code will find the columns that have less than 40% values as null and filter them out.

Comment: My function up there is primarily there for display purposes. I need to inspect each column, make sure that the null values can even be removed first...only then can I actually remove the columns. 

This is for a class presentation - I'll actually get in trouble if I delete null filled columns without confirming if the null values are useful or not.

Comment: What do you mean print the index? Can you give more detail? Also, I added some code to get the summary of missing values.

Comment: I added an example output at the end.

Comment: Making a MultiIndex should do the trick with the first level of the index being the integer location